# Flutter - Black Screen when switching from one Material App to another

Tags: flutter

Our setup is that we have an Login App as a Material app and this leads to two more ore less different apps with different routes - a full app and a guest app.
So we currently have a Material app with the SplashScreen starting a MaterialApp with the LoginScreen and this starting the Full- or - Guest-App.

Everything was working fine till we updated - now there is a black screen when goning from he SplashScreen to the LoginScreen and from the Login-Screen to the Full- or - Guest-App.

Can I avoid the Black Screen without removing the MaterialApps and changing them so Scaffolds (or at least make it white)?

Comment: Provide code of main class and where you switch materials

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can avoid the black screen between transitions without removing the **MaterialApp** widgets. One approach is to set a background color for your **MaterialApp** to ensure that it displays a specific color instead of a black screen during transitions.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      home: SplashScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

I don't know whether it's a best solution but I though it could.